# How can I keep clothing items parented or set to load to specified location while adding them to asset library

Tags: parent, asset-browser

I have characters that I create in cc 4, and I pipeline them over to blender… They’re fully clothed and have accessories… How can I mark those as assets for my asset library and have them stay parented or preset to the same location? This way I can mix and match different outfits on different avatars easily.